# Pause WebView video instead of whole WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have a `WebView` with youtube video and 3 tabs. YouTube video is available in 1st Tab while in other 2 tabs there is a content.

Now i want to pause a video when user moves to other tabs. I have tried with

```
webView.onPause();
```

and

```
Class.forName("android.webkit.WebView")
                                .getMethod("onPause", (Class[]) null)
                                .invoke(webView, (Object[]) null);
```

but it is pausing whole `WebView` and my other 2 tabs are also not responding. How to stop just a video instead of whole `WebView` process

Comment: What about adding javascript code to stop the video, and invoke it from Java after exposing it via `WebView.addJavascriptInterface`?

Comment: basically its youtube video so i dont have any idea about it how to write javascript code.

Answer (score 1):

You can evaluate Javascript from android and stop video playing.

> webView.evaluateJavascript(javascript, callBack);
>   or older versions.
>   webView.loadUrl(javascript);
>   check this
>   https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String,android.webkit.ValueCallback

What type video do you have? iframe or video tag?

Comment: Its inside `iFrame`

Comment: Great add id to iframe and as I showed you webView.evaluateJavascript("document.getElementById("iframe id").stopVideo());

Comment: @RaviRupareliya was it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

On older devices (api <=21) I don't think this is actually possible, but an easy way to retrieve the given idea of a webview's inner controls are to:

Navigate to ../Android/android-sdk/tools/androiduiautomator.bat and open it up.

Make sure your device is connected via an ADB bridge (which it most likely will be)

Take a device screenshot of your screen and hover over the webkit control you want to call onPause which should bring up some information to the right hand side of your screen.

Substitute the id for

```
Class.ForName("yourId")
```

and just call a generic click event which should cause an inner effect of pausing. It could also be

```
Field.getDeclaredField("Id")
```

but I'm not positive. One of those two should procure a desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You write you have A WebView and 3 tab, do you use from that WebView in All tab?

My Solution is that you use from Another WebView in other tab and if it tabs be selected some data that maybe be needed,be send to them.

In fact this don't solve your question, but i hope that can solve your problem.

Comment: Tab is inside WebView only, its not in my `Activity` or `Fragment`

Comment: if you can access to tabs with address, it's possible that create your tab in app and you uses WebView inside them and assigns address to it. and when first page downloaded,you can remove codes of tab to hide them.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with WebViews malfunctioning across my app. I decided to use the complementary function of `onPause()` (*i.e.* `onResume()`) in the same way:

```
Class.forName("android.webkit.WebView")
     .getMethod("onResume", (Class[]) null)
     .invoke(webView, (Object[]) null);
```